# Installation failure

Tags: pi-4

I have an 8GB Raspberry Pi 4 my company gave me to configure. I installed Home Assistant on the 32GB memory card and placed it in it. I am using a Windows 10 system.

The issue I am facing is that on boot-up, the IPv4 address of the Ethernet port is not displayed. This makes it impossible for me to finalize configuration of Home Assistant on my system and addition of devices to the Raspberry Pi.

Please I need assistance on how to startup the Home Assistant and add devices to it.

I tried entering localhost:8123 on my computer browser but it returns a failed page.

Comment: Did you try connecting to homeassistant.local:8123 as per the instructions? https://www.home-assistant.io/installation/raspberrypi

Comment: `localhost:8123` exists only on the computer where you enter it in the browser ... it does not exist within a network

Comment: is the pi at a `ha >` prompt? type `ha network info` and look for the address under `interfaces:`